# My Xamarin.forms images didn't load, can you help me?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a cross-platform app and I'm trying to create a SplashScreen.
I have added all the images to the Ressources folders and put them in Embedded resource but I don't see them.
[Ressource folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mFez.png)

[The result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwDyF.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DVHub"
         x:Class="DVHub.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                BackgroundColor="White">
            <Image x:Name="logo" 
                   Scale="1.4"
                   TranslationX="-120"
                   TranslationY="35"/>
            <Image x:Name="splashScreen"  
                   Scale="1.2"
                   TranslationY="120"/>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The form class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace DVHub
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            logo.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("logo.png");
            splashScreen.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("splashScreen.png");
            Timer timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 3000,
                AutoReset = false
            };
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // await Navigation.PushAsync(new Infos(), true);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Infos());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank in advance

louga31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about ios, but for android you should set Build Action to `AndroidResource`. Hope, this'll help.

Comment: That worked thanks, I have just followed a bad tutorial.